# Set all exponential terms to equal to zero in mathmatica

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I have an expression where I want to set all exponential term to equal to zero at one time

example e^x+xx+tt+e^y+5*e^5, Is there is a direct way to set all e->zero and produce xx+tt?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hi Doaa Taha, welcome to StackOverflow. It may interest you to know that there is a [Mathematica stack exchange](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/). If answers here don't suffice, you could flag your question to ask a moderator to move it there.

Comment: If your "e" is for the base of exponential, note that in Mathematica, a capital letter is used, i.e. E^x or Exp[x] . But as you are going to eliminate them, it may not matter much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
e^x + xx + tt + e^y + 5*e^5 /. e^__ :> 0
(* tt + xx *)
```

Comment: I am knew to stackExchange, sorry about late replying